# How to download a file with string of byte data

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
############ Unable to download using string ###################
some_bytes = str(b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\...')
byte_data_str = some_bytes[2:-1]
byte_data =  byte_data_str.encode()
print(byte_data)
with open("test_file11.xlsx", "wb") as binary_file:
        binary_file.write(byte_data)

############ Able to download on byte data ##############
some_bytes2 = b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\...'   
with open("test_file12.xlsx", "wb") as binary_file:
        binary_file.write(some_bytes2)
```

I am able to download xlsx file directly from byte data but when I am ubable to download from string its not possible. Is there any solution to download the file from string of byte data as an input

Comment: What's wrong with downloading bytes data if it works?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am receiving the input as string. (Posting the byte data from the postman it receives as string.

Comment: What do you mean "download from.."? There's nothing in that code that's about downloading and I don't know what "download from byte data" or "download from string" means.

Comment: @ndc85430 The byte data is a xlsx file. When I able to write the byte data test_file12.xlsx it downloads in the path.